# List of Views a Table contributes of across different databases in Sybase

Tags: view, sybase

Is there a query I can use to find out all the views across a Dataserver using a particular table or set of tables?

Comment: Even when i use sp_depends , It only gives me the table from its home database..even though the view contains tables from other databases as well

Answer (score 0):

the below query will give you all the view that exists in the database:

```
select  * from sysobjects where type ='V'
```

Comment: Yes, but to get it across the dataserver you will need to execute that query in each database.

Comment: Yes thank you.. but this query will give me all the views on one database.. what I want is something like this:
I have database A(table A1) and database B(table B1) . 
Now for example there is a view on database A (VA1) as select * from A1, B1 where a1 = b1
Using the table B1, how can I find the view VA1 ?